# Can we pass a boolean variable while loading control in a aspx page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a aspx page ProjectListInProjectGroup.aspx and a control ProjectListControl.ascx. 
I want to load this control in my aspx page.

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Project/ProjectListControl.ascx" TagName="ProjectListControl"
TagPrefix="AFP" %>
```

This control was used by 2 aspx pages. I want to differentiate those 2 pages calls

while loading I want to pass a boolean variable to that control. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Specify a value when *using* the control (e.g. `<AFP:ProjectListControl ..>`).

See the [Init](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.init%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/Load events as a last-resort if there are no applicable attributes or events, although I recommend use of Data Blinding and using `<%# .. %>` tags to "declaratively" specify properties of the Control in markup.

It doesn't make sense to pass a value *as* the "ASCX is loaded" and it's not possible to [consistently] pass values to the ASCX backing-constructor - that's just *not* how ASCX (or Controls) work in ASP.NET.